# Simplest Tiling of the Floor

Tags: code-golf, grid, tiling

You should write a program or function which receives a string describing the floor as input and outputs or returns the area of the simplest meta-tiling which could create the given pattern of the floor.

The floor is a part of a square grid. Every square tile is colored either azure or black (represented by `a` and `b` in the input).

An example floor:

```
  aaaa
ababab
aaaaa
```

A meta-tiling

- is built from an `N` by `M` rectangular meta-tile of azure and black squares
- the used meta-tiles are identical up to translation (you cannot rotate or mirror them)
- if the sides of two meta-tiles are connected they should connect along their whole length (i.e. meta-tiles tile the space in a grid-like fashion)

An example meta-tile:

```
ba
aa
```

and the meta-tiling created by it:

```
       .
       .
       .
    babababa
    aaaaaaaa
... babababa ...
    aaaaaaaa    
    babababa
    aaaaaaaa
       .
       .
       .
```

This meta-tiling creates the upper shown floor as the left letters show:

```
       .
       .
       .
    ********
    ***aaaa*
... *ababab* ...
    *aaaaa**    
    ********
    ********
       .
       .
       .
```

A meta-tiling is simpler than another if the area of its meta-tile is smaller. Our example has an area of `2*2 = 4` which is the smallest possible for the example floor. So the output should be `4` for the example.

### Input

- A string consisting of the characters `a b space` and `newline` containing at least one `a` or `b`.
- The letters (`ab`) form one 4-connected (side-by-side connected) shape.
- There will be no unnecessary spaces at the front of the rows i.e. there will be at least one row starting with `a` or `b`.
- You can choose of two input format:

  - No unnecessary whitespace at the end of rows (as seen in the examples).
  - Spaces on the right side of the rows to make all rows the same length as the longest row.
- Trailing newline is optional.

### Output

- A single integer, the area of the smallest possible meta-tile whose tiling contains the input floor.

### Examples

Examples are delimited by dashes. The three parts of an example are input, output and one of the possible smallest meta-tiles.

```
a

1

a
-----------------
 aaaa
aaa
a

1

a
-----------------
aabaab
abaa
aaba

6

aab
aba
-----------------
aabaab
a  a a
aabab

18

aabaab
aaaaaa
aababa
-----------------
ba
aaab

8

baaa
aaab
-----------------
 aaaa
ababb
aaaa

10

aaaaa
ababb
-----------------
 a aa
ab ba
 aba

6

aa
ab
ba
-----------------
 aaaa
abab
aaaa

4

aa
ab
-----------------
ba
 ba
  b

4

ba
ab
-----------------
baa
aba
aab

9

baa
aba
aab
-----------------
 aaaa
aabaa
aaaa

6

aaa
aab
```

This is code golf so the shortest entry wins.

Comment: @Ypnypn Every corner has to touch 3 other corners (except the meta-tiles on the edge of the tiling). I stated it as "if the sides of two meta-tiles are connected they should connect along their whole length". So your given example is illegal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### C - 208 bytes

```
w,q,n,m,r,g,u;t(char*f){for(w=0;f[w++]-10;);for(q=1;;q++)for(n=1;m=q/n,n<=q;++n)if(n*m==q){char t[q];bzero(t,q);r=q;for(g=0;f[g];++g){u=g/w%m*n+g%w%n;r=t[u]+f[g]-195?r:0;if(f[g]&64)t[u]=f[g];}if(r)return r;}}
```

Equivalent code before golfing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>

int t(char* f) {
    int w = 0;
    for ( ; f[w++] - 10; );

    for (int q = 1; ; q++) {
        char t[q];
        for (int n = 1; n <= q; ++n) {
            int m = q / n;
            if (n * m == q) {
                bzero(t, q);
                int r = q;
                for (int g = 0; f[g]; ++g) {
                    int u = g / w % m * n + g % w % n;
                    if (t[u] + f[g] == 195) {
                        r = 0;
                    }
                    if (f[g] & 64) {
                        t[u] = f[g];
                    }
                }
                if (r) {
                    return r;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The algorithm is fairly brute force, so it should be reasonably obvious how it works based on the code. Here are a few comments anyway:

- Input is expected to have the form with trailing spaces so that all lines have the same length.
- First loop finds the width by looking for first newline character.
- Outer loop is over candidate meta-tile sizes `q`. Exits with a `return` when a meta-tile can cover the floor. Note that the loop does not need another exit condition since there is always a solution (worst case is size of input).
- First nested loop and following `if` enumerates valid meta-tile width/height combinations for size `q`.
- A character array matching the candidate meta-tile size is zero-initialized.
- Inner loop iterates over all tiles in the floor.
- `u` is the index in the meta-tile that corresponds to the floor tile.
- If both floor tile and meta-tile tile are `a` or `b` and different (sum of `a = 97` and `b = 98` is `195`), there is a mismatch, and the meta-tile size with the attempted dimensions will not work.
- Otherwise, if the floor tile is `a` or `b`, the tile color is copied to the candidate meta-tile.
- Returns size of meta-tile when successful match was made, i.e. if the attempted match was not marked as failed.

Test code used:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int t(char* s);

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", t(
        "a\n"
    ));
    printf("%d\n", t(
        " aaaa\n"
        "aaa  \n"
        "a    \n"
    ));
    printf("%d\n", t(
        "aabaab\n"
        "abaa  \n"
        "aaba  \n"
    ));
    printf("%d\n", t(
        "aabaab\n"
        "a  a a\n"
        "aabab \n"
    ));
    printf("%d\n", t(
        "ba  \n"
        "aaab\n"
    ));
    printf("%d\n", t(
        " aaaa\n"
        "ababb\n"
        "aaaa \n"
    ));
    printf("%d\n", t(
        " a aa\n"
        "ab ba\n"
        " aba \n"
    ));
    printf("%d\n", t(
        " aaaa\n"
        "abab \n"
        "aaaa \n"
    ));
    printf("%d\n", t(
        "ba \n"
        " ba\n"
        "  b\n"
    ));
    printf("%d\n", t(
        "baa\n"
        "aba\n"
        "aab\n"
    ));
    printf("%d\n", t(
        " aaaa\n"
        "aabaa\n"
        "aaaa \n"
    ));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
1
6
18
8
10
6
4
4
9
6
```

Answer (score 6):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), <sup><s>53</s></sup> <sup><s>37</s></sup> 36 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
{⌊/×/¨⍸(~6∊' a'∧/⍤⍳⍵⊢⌸⍥,⍨|)⍤0 2⍨⍳⍴⍵}
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=q37U06V/eLr@oRWPendo1Jk96uhSV0hUf9SxXP9R75JHvZsf9W591LXoUc@OR71LdR71rqjRBIobKBgBmWDZLUAFtQA&f=y00sUXjUNuFRV5OhguGj3i3qiepcuYklOhCxR20T1RUSgUBdQR1KoksnJiYBEUgmCaosCY8aBYVEBZiqJHRlSVBrknA6AagpCaImEYs7FaCKFMAGKWBxCLJBUHOwOgJqggIWJ0K1Q/yAO6xggQG1gCvt0IpcUFD3zlUABrSCmYKhhYKFgqEBkGUChJYKZgA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=train&n=f)

Instead of partitioning, this one groups the characters in the matrix by their 2D indices modulo current size. I came up with it independently, but apparently it's the same as [Zgarb](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209609/78410)'s idea. But there's a funky part in this solution: in order to test if a group contains both `a` and `b`, it maps space/a/b into 1, 2, 3 respectively via find-index function, and calculates their LCM to see if it is 6.

---

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 53 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```apl
{⌊/×/¨⍸{∧/,⍲/¨'ab'∘∊¨⊃{⍉,⌿↑⍺⊂⍵}/(⊂,⍨⍴⍴¨⍺↑¨≡)⍵}∘⍵¨⍳⍴⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZHPSsNAEMbv@xRzawMpMTaE9uxFr9YX2EXqpaAnoYRcFEIausUeRC8KnsxNUAviRYhvMi8Sv93YPxTEBHE32Qyb75vfzqw8G3WOx3J0elJGPM28zxuvyM891nnE6aPnsn7GRkuqFqe3nGZFztllxHri8vSDkznrd84uWC9ir91m/YrIwQcy/EjmRe477rfAJNALZOfkCnlfKnUs1lzWb/9GXQPLPwIRQJ/bbBtInjw4PwCHqJj1DCmLp67JNrseHO5hPdo/GJRDwhZY97E1@USs78gXUnS2h9jSdpdakhjCvrVdIfQKjzCrjesDeysvkaTKrX6371b2nlD2sKo@cGdZIjhK2LB@neaIxkrAUpM6gw1qM2hgSrQ8ql9lX6gKJpr0JlzdfnWPWITtGWaIq6Ie2ocowOxT@AU)

A function that takes a character matrix as the argument. Basically, tries all possible tile sizes, testing if partitioning by that size would give at most one of `ab` on every cell.

#### Illustration

```apl
Example input:
 a aa
ab ba
 aba
Example tile size: 2 rows, 2 columns
Partition:
+--+--+-+
| a| a|a|
|ab| b|a|
+--+--+-+
| a|ba| |
+--+--+-+
Cells collected into a tile:
+------+------+
|  a b |aa aa |
+------+------+
|a a   |bb    |
+------+------+
Since top left cell has both a and b, this tile size is invalid.
```

#### How the code works

```apl
{⌊/×/¨⍸{∧/,⍲/¨'ab'∘∊¨⊃{⍉,⌿↑⍺⊂⍵}/(⊂,⍨⍴⍴¨⍺↑¨≡)⍵}∘⍵¨⍳⍴⍵}
             ⍝ ⍵ ← Char matrix
        ⍳⍴⍵  ⍝ Generate possible tile sizes as a matrix of length-2 vectors
{...}∘⍵¨     ⍝ Test if each tile size is valid...
             ⍝   ⍵ ← Input char matrix, ⍺ ← tile size
(⊂,⍨⍴⍴¨⍺↑¨≡)⍵  ⍝ Create partition vectors and join with ⍵ for RTL reduction
(         ≡)⍵  ⍝ Depth of ⍵, which always gives 1 for valid input
       ⍺↑¨     ⍝ Overtake 1 to the length of each of ⍺, e.g. (1 0)(1 0 0)
    ⍴⍴¨        ⍝ Cycle each to the length of the dimensions of ⍵,
               ⍝ e.g. (1 0 1 0 1)(1 0 0 1 0)
 ⊂,⍨           ⍝ Append the enclosed ⍵
⊃{⍉,⌿↑⍺⊂⍵}/  ⍝ Partition and collect all cells at the same position in the tile
 {       }/  ⍝ Reduce by...
      ⍺⊂⍵    ⍝ Partition ⍵ into consecutive columns at 1s of ⍺
     ↑       ⍝ Mix so that short partition is padded with spaces
   ,⌿        ⍝ Collect the cells at the same position
  ⍉          ⍝ Transpose to do the same for rows
⊃            ⍝ Disclose one level of nesting (which is a side effect of /)
∧/,⍲/¨'ab'∘∊¨  ⍝ Test if no tile position contains both a and b
      'ab'∘∊¨  ⍝ For each tile position, evaluate (has a)(has b)
   ⍲/¨         ⍝ Reduce each by NAND; 1 if the tile position has at most one of ab
∧/,            ⍝ Test if it is true for all positions
⌊/×/¨⍸  ⍝ Extract the answer (the smallest area)
     ⍸  ⍝ 1-based coordinates of ones; the tile sizes which passed the test
⌊/×/¨   ⍝ Minimum of the areas
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 30 bytes

```
ḟ(SδV(ΛË←k→f←δṁz,¶⁰¤Ṫeo¢ḣ)↔Ḋ)1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AVIArf9odXNr///huJ8oU860VijOm8OL4oaQa@KGkmbihpDOtOG5gXoswrbigbDCpOG5qmVvwqLhuKMp4oaU4biKKTH///8gIGFiYgphYiBhYgpiYmFi)

### Explanation

I loop through all nonnegative integers until I find one that, when split into two factors in some way, gives a horizontal and vertical period for the input patch.
The period is checked by grouping the 2D indices of non-space characters by their values modulo the two numbers, and checking that each group contains equal characters.

```
ḟ(…)1   Starting from 1, find a number that satisfies (…).

SδV(…)↔Ḋ   We're looking at a number, say n=6.
       Ḋ   Divisors: d = [1,2,3,6]
S     ↔    Reverse and apply to both:
 δV(…)     does any pair from d and its reverse satisfy (…)?
           For n=6, the pairs are (1,6), (2,3), (3,2), and (6,1).

ΛË←k→f←δṁz,¶⁰¤Ṫeo¢ḣ   Check if (a,b) is a valid metatile.
             ¤        For both a and b:
                  ḣ     take range from 1 to it
                o¢      and cycle it infinitely.
              Ṫ       Combine these by taking outer product by
               e      pairing.
                      For (a,b)=(2,3), this gives the infinite 2D array
                      A=[[[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,1],..],
                         [[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[2,1],..],
                         [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,1],..],
                         ..]
           ¶⁰         The input, split at newlines.
       δṁ             For each row of it and A:
         z,             zip them (discarding overflowing rows and pairs of A)
       δṁ               and concatenate the results.
                      Now we have a list of pairs like ('a',[2,3]) that contain
                      a character from the input and its coordinates mod (a,b).
     f←               Keep those whose left part is truthy, i.e. not a space.
   k→                 Classify (into separate lists) by right part.
Λ                     Does every class
 Ë←                   have all equal left parts?
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-r`, 52 bytes

```
MN:$*_M{$&{$*$Q*$.aDCs}M_UWa@1MMyUW@a}FI\,#gCP\,#@Yg
```

Takes input from lines of stdin, with trailing spaces as needed. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P/f189KRSvet1pFrVpFSyVQS0Uv0cW5uNY3PjQ80cHQ17cyNNwhsdbNM0ZHOd05AEg6RKb//6@QqJCYyJWYpJCUyKWQmJSo8F@3CAA)

Approach taken from [Bubbler's APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207370/16766): We try all possible meta-tile dimensions, filtering for the ones that have a unique non-space character at each position. `UW` (unweave) is very useful for grouping the input grid by tile positions. We then multiply each successful pair of dimensions to get the area of the tile, and take the minimum.

Leave a comment if you'd like a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 44 bytes

```
∧ℕf⟨≡z↔⟩∋[X,Y]×.&ṇġ↙Xz₁ġᵐ²↙Yz₁ᵐ²zᵐ{c;Ṣx=}ᵐ²∧
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//1HH8kctU9MezV/xqHNh1aO2KY/mr3zU0R0doRMZe3i6ntrDne1HFj5qmxlR9aip8cjCh1snHNoE5EaCuGBOFZCsTrZ@uHNRhW0tRLpj@f//SgqJComJXIlJCkmJXAqJSYlK/x0B)

A port of [Zgarb's Husk answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209609/16766). Brachylog doesn't have infinite lists or cyclic indexing, so instead I'm using the "groups" predicate `ġ` (`[1,2,3,4,5]ġ₂ -> [[1,2],[3,4],[5]]`) and then zip `z` (`[[1,2],[3,4],[5]]z₁ -> [[1,3,5],[2,4]]`) to get lists of the characters at tile-equivalent positions.